# Table Sorter updateAll method does not seem to be doing anything

Tags: tablesorter

I am feeling like I am losing my mind. Have been at this for days with a colleague. We have a DIV on an intranet site that is loading its content using the load function to grab a second page of which contains a blank table (the structure exists but the Tbody initially contains no content. In the call-back function of the load a further get is used to pull in the table rows from a third page:

```
<div class="AlwaysOpenContentDocs" id="Ref_Doc_Lib">            
        <script type='text/javascript'>         
            $("#Ref_Doc_Lib").load("./Documents/Docs_View_Edit_new.asp", function() {
                    //Initiate the table sort jquery plugin on the table                            
                    $('#Docs_Library_Table').tablesorter({
                            namespace : 'Docs_Library_Table',
                            widgets        : ['zebra', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders'],
                            usNumberFormat : false,
                            sortReset      : true,
                            sortRestart    : true
                    }); 
            
                    $.get("./Documents/Docs_View_Table_Data.asp", function(html) {                
                      $("#Docs_Library_Table tbody").append(html).trigger("updateAll");               
                    }); 
                        
            });
        </script>   
    </div>
```

This works and the table is initialised and the new rows are inserted into the tbody as expected.

The issue is that the update all function seems to not be working. I updated the jquery.tablesorter.js file to add a console log line into the update all function and it never gets executed so I am confident the line calling the function is not executing correctly but I can not for the life of me work out why.

Also interestingly, with that line in the code the new rows have their styles applied and with out they remain white rows (not zebra) but then when test the search or sort it behaves like its still only the initial empty table.

The content of the two external files are as such:
Docs_View_Edit_new.asp

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="Docs_Library_Table" >
            <thead>
                <tr class="AddReportTableText">
                    <th style="width:200px;">Document Name</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Document Type</th>
                    <th style="width:400px;">Description</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">TRIM Reference</th>        
                    <% If bAuth_Views_Admin_Docs = True Or bAuth_Buttons_Global_Admin_All = True Then %>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <% End If %>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        <table>
```

Docs_View_Table_Data.asp:

```
<tr class="AddReportTableText" style="width:200px;">
                    <td>
                        <b><% response.write objrs.fields.item(1).value %></b>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <% response.write objrs.fields.item(2).value %>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td style="width:400px;">
                        <div id="disp-desc-<% response.write objrs.fields.item(0).value%>" style="display:block;"><% response.write objrs.fields.item(3).value %></div>         
                    </td>
                
                    <td>
                        <div id="disp-TRIM-<% response.write objrs.fields.item(0).value%>" style="width:100%; text-align:center; display:block;">
                            <a href="http://pdcwpbvrs200/Dashboard_Files/Admin_Reference_Docs/<% response.write objrs.fields.item(5).value %>"><% response.write objrs.fields.item(4).value %></a>
                        </div>
                        
                    </td>
                    <% If bAuth_Views_Admin_Docs = True Or bAuth_Buttons_Global_Admin_All = True Then %>    
                    <td>
                        <center><input type="button" class="defaultFont" id="btn-nf-edit-<% response.write objrs.fields.item(0).value%>" value="Delete" style="width: 70px; display:block;" onclick="AdminDocs_btn_nf_click('Delete', '<% response.write objrs.fields.item(0).value %>')"></input></center>
                    </td>
                    <% End If %>
                </tr>
```

Comment: I wouldn't reocmmend using `updateAll` if the number of columns in the table don't change - if they are, I would destroy the tablesorter instance, then reinitialize it. If you're not changing the number of columns, switch to using `update`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to get it to load correctly by structuring the chain of events as such:

```
function initialise_documents_library(){
//Retrieve the dynamic table rows for documents
$.get("./Documents/Testing/Docs_View_Table_Data.asp", function(html) {
    $.getScript( "http://pdcwpbvrs200/Dashboard_Files/JavaScript/jquery.tablesorter.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        $.getScript( "http://pdcwpbvrs200/Dashboard_Files/JavaScript/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                //Load the table structure
                $("#Ref_Doc_Lib").load("./Documents/Testing/Docs_View_Edit_new.asp", function() {
                    
                    //Append the data rows into the structure
                    $("#Docs_Library_Table tbody").append(html);
                        
                    //Initiate the table sort jquery plugin on the table                            
                    $('#Docs_Library_Table').tablesorter({
                            namespace : 'Docs_Library_Table',
                            widgets        : ['zebra', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders'],
                            usNumberFormat : false,
                            sortReset      : true,
                            sortRestart    : true
                    }); 
                });
        });
    });
});
```

}

For some reason our console testing showed there was no access to the scripts which are included in the document HEAD tags from within the call-back functions. As soon as we added  nested getScript calls ahead of the load then the table initialised as expected.

Whilst I understand event chaining conceptually I do not have a clue why it was not able to initialise without the getScript calls to re-import the libraries?

Comment: In addition if i take the scripts out of the head it then starts to behave erratically (especially in IE), sometimes initialising on page load, other times not. With the scripts included in the head and then re-imported within the function it seems to load correctly each time in IE, Edge and Chrome.